# React client calling server which calls 0Auth server not appearing, HTTP 303 returned

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0

I have a react-node(express) server. The client is running on localhost:3000 whilst the server is on localhost:8888. I am attempting to authenticate a user for the spotifyAPI but cannot seem to get the login page to appear if I try via the client.

Currently I have a react component that does a basic call to my node server on the press of a button which calls the authenticate spotify api

```
  function FunctionalComponent() {
  const [topTracks, settopTracks] = useState([]);

  function handleOnClick() {
    axios.get("/login").then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Click here to login</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The proxy is facing localhost:8888.

This calls my node server.

```
var SpotifyWebApi = require("spotify-web-api-node");
```

var cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const scopes = ["user-top-read"];

var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: "",
  clientSecret: "",
  redirectUri: "http://localhost:8888/callback",
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  if (!spotifyApi.getAccessToken()) {
    res.redirect(spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes, undefined, true));
  } else {
    res.send("ass");
  }
});

app.get("/callback", (req, res) => {
  console.log(res);
  const error = req.query.error;
  const code = req.query.code;
  const state = req.query.state;

  if (error) {
    console.error("Callback Error:", error);
    res.send(`Callback Error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }

  spotifyApi
    .authorizationCodeGrant(code)
    .then((data) => {
      const access_token = data.body["access_token"];
      const refresh_token = data.body["refresh_token"];
      const expires_in = data.body["expires_in"];

      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token);
      spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(refresh_token);

      console.log("access_token:", access_token);
      console.log("refresh_token:", refresh_token);

      console.log(
        `Sucessfully retreived access token. Expires in ${expires_in} s.`
      );

      setInterval(async () => {
        const data = await spotifyApi.refreshAccessToken();
        const access_token = data.body["access_token"];

        spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token);
      }, (expires_in / 2) * 1000);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error getting Tokens:", error);
      res.send(`Error getting Tokens: ${error}`);
    });
});

app.get("/getTopTracks", (req, res) => {
  spotifyApi.getMyTopTracks().then(function (data) {
    res.send(data.body.items);
  });
});

app.listen(8888, () =>
  console.log(
    "HTTP Server up. Now go to http://localhost:8888/login in your browser."
  )
);
```

From here, how do I link the user back to the original page once logged in.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=eca82f597115423cac9d1125e0fb97c4&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/callback&scope=user-top-read' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

[image: here is the 303 response I get]

Comment: Did you register the redirect uri in Spotify when creating a client? There might also be settings for allowed origins that can call the Spotify API. Also check if the Spotify production API doesn't have some restrictions on localhost callbacks. Maybe there is a sandbox API that will work with localhost.